# Simplification of boolean functions

Tags: boolean-algebra

I have the following problem:

Simplify the following Boolean functions by algebraic transformation. Express the result in disjunctive normal form (DNF).

i) $j(a, b, c, d)=a \bar{b}+c+\bar{a} \bar{c} d+b \bar{c} d$

ii) $k(a, b, c, d)=\overline{\bar{a} b \bar{c}} \cdot \overline{a \bar{b} \bar{c}}$

iii) $l(a, b, c, d)=a b c+a b \bar{d}+a \bar{c}+\bar{a} \bar{b} \bar{c} d+\bar{a} c$

iv) $m(a, b, c, d)=(a+\bar{b}+c) \cdot \overline{a b+\bar{a} \bar{c}}$

For this I have the rules shown below at hand:

[image]

Note: $+$ means or and $*/\text{no dot}$ means and.

I would now be interested, since I have been trying my hand at these tasks for some time now, if there is a structured approach to this. Or is it here like with the application of binomial formulas that one must recognize the laws?

Comment: There are some systematic methods for doing this. For example, look up Karnaugh Maps (K-Maps). And there are even algorithmic methods for this that guarantee to find the ‘simplest’ (defined in some specific) way: see Quine-McCluskey algorithm. But, after some practice, you can typically get pretty good at this without any further crutches. I would like to add at least one more law to your list though: Adjacency says that $xy+xy’=x$. Together with those two Absorption Laws, those are rules that you typically use a lot to simplify

Comment: Thank you for that comment.